# How can i get the length of the text in redactorjs?

Tags: jquery

I'm using [redactorjs](http://redactorjs.com/), It's a WYSIWYG editor on jQuery. I have a textbox and I want to validate its length to be not more than 10,000.

The problem is when my text box is converted to redactorjs WYSIWYG editor, when I'm validating the length of the textbox, it also includes the HTML tags created by redactorjs.

I want to know how to get the raw text of the textbox without the html tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the page you linked I tried:

```
$(".redactor_frame").contents().find("#page").html().length
//980
$(".redactor_frame").contents().find("#page").text().length
//781
```

Where `"#page"` is the WYSIWYG container inside the `".redactor_frame"` iframe

Comment: Might be worth mentioning here that redactor is no longer using an iframe for it's editor.  It does all it's magic in a contentEditable div, so this answer might not be valid for the newer version of redactor.